# Get password from mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this columns on my table:

```
QuizId  QuizName    CreatedBy   Created     ModifiedBy  Modified    AccessType  Status  TotalTime   PassedScore     QuestionCount   QuestionTime    Description     RandomQuestion  LagTime     AttemptCount    AttemptPeriod   AdminEmail  ResultScaleId   Anonymous   FullStatistics  FullStatisticsOnSuccess     FullStatisticsOnFail    MailGroupList   StartDate   EndDate     AutoMailToUser  ExtraParams     ResultTemplateType  PassedTemplateId    FailedTemplateId    PrintPassedTemplateId   PrintFailedTemplateId   MailPassedTemplateId    MailFailedTemplateId    CertificateFailedTemplateId     CertificatePassedTemplateId     AdminMailTemplateId     Metadata    StartImmediately    HideCorrectAnswers  Access  asset_id    AccessPass
```

and this javascript code

```
<SCRIPT>
function passWord()
{
 var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password','');
 if(pass1 && pass1.toLowerCase() == "mypass")
 {
  if (YAHOO.ARISoft.validators.alertSummaryValidators.validate()) YAHOO.ARISoft.page.pageManager.submitForm(); return false;
  } else {
  alert('Incorect password!');
  return false;
 }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

The scripts is working fine, but how can i get from mysql head columns "AccessPass" and replace in javascript "mypass" to read every password from every "QuizId".

New code must be something like:

```
<sql code generate mypass>

<SCRIPT>
function passWord()
{
 var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password','');
 if(pass1 && pass1.toLowerCase() == "$mypass")
 {
  if (YAHOO.ARISoft.validators.alertSummaryValidators.validate()) YAHOO.ARISoft.page.pageManager.submitForm(); return false;
  } else {
  alert('Incorect password!');
  return false;
 }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Thx a lot!

Comment: This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved myself:

```
<SCRIPT>
function passWord()
<?php $mypassword = $this->testes->AccessPass; ?>
{
 var pass1 = prompt('Insert the password:','');
 if(pass1 && pass1.toLowerCase() == "<?php echo $mypassword; ?>")
 {
  if (YAHOO.ARISoft.validators.alertSummaryValidators.validate()) YAHOO.ARISoft.page.pageManager.submitForm(); return false;
  } else {
  alert('Invalid Password!');
  return false;
 }
}
</SCRIPT>
```

It works great!